# Laravel handling empty relations in eager loading

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am working on a Laravel query, and my goal is to load the `programs` with their relations. I'm using eager loading to load the `calculation` relations along with the `calculation.calculationBusSizes` relation with a specific where clause. Everything works fine, but I've encountered a problem that I can't solve.

In some cases, it loads a `program` where the `calculationBusSizes` relation returns an empty array. I want to prevent this and load the `programs` only when `calculationBusSizes` is not an empty object. I've tried doing it like this:

```
$programs = Program::query()
  ->where('has_programs_id', '=', $offer->id)
  ->where('has_programs_type', '=' , 'App\Models\Offer')
  ->with(['calculation.calculationBusSizes' => function($query) use ($company){
     $query->where('bus_company_id', '=', $company->id);
  }])
  ->has('calculation.calculationBusSizes')
  ->get();
```

But it still return the programs where the `calculationBusSizes` relation is empty, I don't find any examples that could help, so I would appreciate if someone could help!

Comment: @JohnLobo That comment will look a lot less messy as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `withWhereHas()` which can solves your problem. For reference visit and read this link: https://dev.to/othmane_nemli/laravel-wherehas-and-with-550o

```
$programs = Program::query()
            ->where('has_programs_id', '=', $offer->id)
            ->where('has_programs_type', '=' , 'App\Models\Offer')
            ->withWhereHas([
               'calculation.calculationBusSizes' => function($query) use ($company){ 
                  $query->where('bus_company_id', '=', $company->id); 
            }])->get();
```

Comment: Also visit this one for reference: https://laraveldaily.com/post/eloquent-withwherehas-method